# What is this worksheet on "edit links" referencing?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have to make changes to a worksheet that references another worksheet in *edit links*.

[image: Edit links dialog]

However, I don't know how to tell what the references are. I don't see components of that worksheet references in any other excel dialog. Are there other places besides the following I should be looking?

**Workbook Connections**
[image: Workbook Connections]

**Existing connections (and tables)**
[image: Connections]
[image: Tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the range is referenced in the name manager:

[image: Name manager]